# Laravel - Target class [PostsController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error message when I try to access this url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/first-post

**Error Message:**

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PostsController] does not exist.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/first-post

**but I can see that PostsController class exists.**

**web.php**
[image]

**PostsController.php**
[image]

Are there any reasons and how can I fix it?

Note: I am using laravel 8.0.3

Comment: import class on `web.php`  add this `use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;`

Comment: you mean I need use:  `use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;` on `web.php` page?

Comment: remove the `namespace App\Htt...\PostsController` in `PostsController.php` and then open CLI on your working directory, then [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-). see if it works.

Comment: @creativeartbd yes as u r usng `::class` so u need to import

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @KamleshPaul but earlier we didn't do that. What happened now?

Comment: @creativeartbd please, paste your code, so other can easily edit it and submit answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alternatively you might get the same error message if the controller class has a syntax error.